# "flutter_barcode_scanner" package not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

No problem in the debug mode but in the release mode showing error
"startView: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.texol.taskforces/com.amolg.flutterbarcodescanner.BarcodeCaptureActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared ?"
like this.
I changed the activity name but it doesn't work for me